# Better way to do the class initialization in angular4 typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, angular6, typescript2.0

Better way to initialize inner class inside outer class in angular4 .

Here  have  a outer class name ProductsModel which contains ProductsListModel.
I have to send the ProductId string array to server side request.The below code is working fine when initialize the inner class inside outer class.

when not initialize:

```
  export  class ProductsModel{
        productList : ProductListModel;

        }
```

**when doing this I have got a below error message:**

> cannot set property ProductId be undefined.

So I have initialize below like this which is working as expected, is there any better way to initialize

```
Outer Class:

export  class ProductsModel{
productList = new ProductListModel();

}


export class ProductListModel{
ProductId:string[];

}

-- app. component.ts

export class AppComponent {

// initialsize  outer class here:

products = new ProductsModel();

in this subscribe:


DetailsByProductID(){


this.products.productList.ProductId = ['8901','8902'];
//pass the model object here 

this.ProductService.fetchByPID(this.products).subscribe(resposne=>console.log(response)});


}
}
```

Comment: typo in your code: `resposne` instead of `response`

Answer (score 1):

You should do the initialization only in the component, keep your classes as it is with properties.

You are getting the error "Cannot set property of **`ProductId`** be undefined." because product is null.

You can do the initialization within your component like the same way you have did inside the class.

```
products = new ProductsModel();

this.products.productList = new ProductListModel();

this.products.productList.ProductId = ['8901','8902'];
```

Comment: @sajeethran Okay thank you is there any other standardized way to initialize inside component

Comment: what do you mean by standardized way? if you really want to have default values you can define in the class itself.

Comment: okay got it while code-revew  i have got a comment like don't initialize a class inside component load , therefore i have asked this question.

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do, as I said if you need default value you should do it in the class

Comment: That "don't initialize a class inside component load" comment normally means to move the initialization code from the component's constructor to the components `ngOnInit` method.But it's hard to tell if that is what they meant in this context without seeing a bit more of your code.